# prove $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t^2}dt $ converges

Tags: calculus

Show the convergence of :  $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t^2}dt $$

I believe I can prove this with the Cauchy integral convergence test but was looking for any simpler method.

Comment: I reformatted your question accordingly.  Hint:  At $\infty$ the integrand is bounded by $e^{-t}$ and that integral certainly converges.

Comment: Worth noting that the integral can be computed exactly...a famous computation due to Gauss.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)

Comment: For moderately large $t$ the integrand is less than $1/t^2$ which has convergent integral on any $[a,\infty),$ where $a>0.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It suffices to observe that on $[0,1)$, $$f(t) = e^{-t^2} \le e^0 = 1,$$ and on $[1,\infty)$, $$f(t) \le te^{-t^2},$$ consequently $$\int_{t=0}^\infty f(t) \, dt \le \int_{t=0}^1 dt + \int_{t=1}^\infty te^{-t^2} \, dt = 1 + \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[-\frac{e^{-t^2}}{2} \right]_{t=1}^n = 1 + \frac{1}{2e}.$$

Comment: clever, multiplying by t, to make the function even LARGER, but one I can integrate. thanks.

Comment: @ChuckS., if you find the answer useful, you can "accept it" as the best answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.

Comment: A very similar answer (that was since deleted by its author) using a comparison with $e^{-t}$ was also perfectly legitimate, although the bound is not quite as tight as if one were to compare with $te^{-t^2}$.  An interesting question is if the bound for $f$ on $[0,1)$ can be improved without sacrificing too much simplicity.

Comment: I will select answer 1 as best, as it makes me think I am bounding the integral by going in the wrong direction, but then you "capture" it as convergent. The third answer that uses what I knew as the "integral test" for convergence of an infinite series also was instructive to me, because it got my head straight that the "integral test" ALSO means that a convergent series implies convergence of the related integral. I will have to review much more of my old material (50 years ago) to follow the proof referenced by lulu to understand that. All answers very good.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-1}},$$
which shows that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n}$ converges. Also, it is easy to see that $e^{-n^2}\le e^{-n}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, thus
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2}\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n}$$
and by using the comparison test, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n^2}$ converges, and so is $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}dt$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a rather easy way. On interval $(0,1)$ the given function is convergent and on interval $1$ to infinity it is easy to see that your function is less than the function  $y=e^{-t}$ The latter integral is very easy to integrate on interval $1$ to infinity. In fact that value is $1/e$.

Comment: Yes, I see the function comparison test. I think that integral from 1 to inf is 1/e but the result is the same. thanks.

Comment: Yes, thanks for bringing that up. (I was thinking about zero instead of 1)...